# Emails when changing DNS

Tags: dns, email

I moved my site to another server and updated DNS. Now if I send e-mail to my e-mail address I don't receive it. I know DNS update take up to 48 hours.

It has been 5 hours from DNS changes and I don't receive e-mail anymore to old server if I check webmail. This means DNS have already been updated, right?

But I also don't see it inside webmail for new server. Where did e-mails stuck? Will be all e-mails sent during DNS upgrade released and I will finally receive it when dns update is over? I hope somebody can explain me how this works.

Comment: When you say you "moved your site" - what exactly did you do? Are you moving _everything_? ie. Website, email, master DNS records?

Comment: I transfered all files to new server, updated ns1 and ns2 inside godaddy and created new e-mail accounts in new server.

Comment: Did you update any DNS MX records?? That is what is require for e-mail MX = Mail eXchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that the new sever had mail server disabled. Once it was enabled e-mails started going to inbox.

Comment: Thanks for returning to update us. Since the solution was unrelated to changing your DNS, the question's being closed. You can still accept your answer however to indicate to others what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that your MX records have been updated to reflect the new server address, then double check in your hosting panel that all your old email addresses gave been recreated on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved your website to another server then you might need to recreate the webmail ids as last time I did the same i recreated all of my ids and along with that i had to reconfigure all of them to my gmail account using IMAP4 settings. Please try this will surely work.